# Copy Excel range without background colors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that copies tables from Excel to Word.

```
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherData").Range("N90").Value = True Then
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TableForOL").Range("B6:F16").Copy
            With wdRng
            Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
            rngPara.Style = "Data"
            rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
            .Tables(.Tables.Count).Range.Paragraphs.Indent
            .Font.Hidden = 0
            Set rngPara = Nothing
            End With
        Else
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TableForOL").Range("B6:F6").Copy
            With wdRng
            Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
            rngPara.Style = "Data"
            rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
            .Tables(.Tables.Count).Range.Paragraphs.Indent
            .Font.Hidden = 0
            Set rngPara = Nothing
            End With
        End If
```

This table has certain background in Excel that would be good to keep even after copy-paste process. However I don't want it in Word. Currently I have to use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TableForOL").Range("B6:F2621").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
```

That is removing all backgrounds.

Is there any way to do it the other way so that background color would net follow to Word document but would stay as it is in Excel.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteexceltable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try changing of

```
rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

with

```
rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the existing background color first:

```
origBG = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TableForOL").Range("B6:F2621").Interior.ColorIndex
```

Then blank it:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TableForOL").Range("B6:F2621").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
```

After the `Copy` operation, you can restore it:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TableForOL").Range("B6:F2621").Interior.ColorIndex = origBG
```